# Get Physical Keyboard Layout Programmatically

Tags: winapi, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to programmatically find out what kind of keyboard a computer has (i.e. where keys are located, and what extra keys are present in which locations)?

A little error is acceptable, if the keyboard is very non-standard, but in general, the point is to construct an on-screen keyboard-like application that can dynamically draw the keyboard layout on the screen, with high accuracy.

Comment: What language(s) are you using?

Comment: Whatever Windows is using :) ... does the solution differ based on the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mechanism by which a keyboard can tell Windows what its physical layout looks like.  Easy to see with the Windows version of an on-screen keyboard, osk.exe.  It seems to be able to guess the form-factor of the machine (laptop vs desktop) but on my laptop it doesn't match the layout of the keyboard.

Use the osk.exe layout as a template so nobody can complain that yours doesn't match well.

Comment: Is there really *no* way to, say, pass data directly to/from the driver to get this info?

Comment: No.  Not even the driver cares exactly where a user puts her fingers.

Comment: This might sound silly, but is there any way to bypass the driver and query the keyboard itself?? (A keyboard equivalent of a SCSI pass-through request, for example?)

Comment: Yes, that is silly.  You are still missing the point, there is no protocol between the keyboard controller and the driver that passes anything resembling physical layout info.  It just sends a simple byte with a scan code number when a key is pressed.

Comment: Hm... interesting. Wonder why they didn't decide to standardize this info and have the keyboard report it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 5):

when connected to a computer, keyboards sends "scan codes" to the operating system. on windows, scan codes are then converted into virtual keys (a hardware independent mapping of the keyboard) then to real characters.

the [`MapVirtualKeyEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646307%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function of the windows API allows you to translate between scan codes, virtual keys and characters. it should also be able to tell you if a key is non-existing.

together with [`GetKeyboardLayout()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which tells you which keybaord is active at any point in time (keyboard layout can be different for different running applications), it should allow you to build a pretty accurate map of the keyboard.

anyway, have a look at the [`keyboard input section of the MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645530%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

i will add that all keyboards have almost the same layout. although there is no way to know where a key is physically located, you can probably guess from the scan code and basic knowledge of your own keyboards.

Comment: But in that way You get only the key number the layout has, right?
Or that retrieved number includes media buttons?

Answer (score 2):

**Update from 2023**

There is a new [KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ns-ntddkbd-keyboard_extended_attributes) struct and [IOCTL_KEYBOARD_QUERY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ni-ntddkbd-ioctl_keyboard_query_extended_attributes) IOCTL added in Windows 10 that can return additional keyboard info.

See "15.18 Descriptive Controls" in the [recent HID Usage Tables spec](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_4.pdf). These was from adopted [HID Usage Table Review Request 42:  Consumer Page Keyboard Assist Controls](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hutrr42c_0.pdf) from 2013.

```cpp
bool QueryInfo(const ScopedHandle& interfaceHandle)
{
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ns-ntddkbd-keyboard_extended_attributes

    KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES extended_attributes{ KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT_VERSION_1 };
    DWORD len = 0;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(interfaceHandle.get(), IOCTL_KEYBOARD_QUERY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES, nullptr, 0, &extended_attributes, sizeof(extended_attributes), &len, nullptr))
        return false;

    DCHECK_EQ(len, sizeof(extended_attributes));

    FormFactor = extended_attributes.FormFactor;
    KeyType = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    PhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.PhysicalLayout;
    VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout;
    IETFLanguageTagIndex = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    ImplementedInputAssistControls = extended_attributes.ImplementedInputAssistControls;

    return true;
}
```

But seems these is not adopted by vendors and my modern `Logitech MX Keys` keyboard returns zero values in these fields..